# BottomSheetBehaviour is dissmised when user clicks on back

Tags: java, android

I have a BottomSheetBehaviour in my layout, and it works absolutely fine. The problem is, that whenever user clicks on back button, it becomes invisible(or gone). How can I prevent it to be non-dissmissable?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem has been solved. No need to reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a layout for your bottom sheet as:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="16dp"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="260dp"//change according to your need
          app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
        
         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        //your design here       
       </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

include this layout in your main layout file

```
<include layout="@layout/layout_name" />
```

now you can use your bottom sheet in your activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);
    
    View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottomSheet);
    //add behaviour as
     BottomSheetBehavior<View> bottomSheetBehavior =BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    //access your views inside bottomSheet as
    
    TextView textView = bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
    
}
```

Comment: happy to help!! happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Just override onCancel() or onDismiss().

```
@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
//   super.onCancel(dialog); // comment this out
   Toast.makeText(MainApp.get(), "CANCEL REQUESTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Or override `onBackPressed` in `onCreateDialog` function when you're crating the dialog

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new Dialog(getActivity(), getTheme()){
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
           Toast.makeText(MainApp.get(), "CANCEL REQUESTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I am trying it now

Comment: Bro on @Override a red line is appearing. It is saying that Method does not override method from its superclass

Comment: Are extending the fragment from `BottomSheetDialogFragment`? You can't override this behaviour if you extend your fragment from `BottomSheetBehaviour `

Comment: No, I am not using BottomSheetDialog. I am using BottomSheetBehaviour.  https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-behavior/

Comment: A standard bottom sheet

Comment: I believe you have to use a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` anyway. The bottom sheet is a fragment. Just override the function in that fragment. For example, it's `ModalBottomSheet` on material.io. If you're sure that this will not work then override `onBackPressed` function in `onCreateDialog`

Comment: I don't want to use a bottomsheetdialogfragment.

Comment: In BottomSheetDialogFragment, the problem is that, the user cannot interact with the rest of the UI. For interacting with it, the bottomsheetdialogfragment must be dissmissed and I don't want this.

Comment: Hello @tpbafk kindly reply

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to do it without the fragment